# How to edit appended data?

Tags: python, append

How do I edit appended data so that only the race number is left. Apparently, you can modify m and r prior to appending to do this. Any idea how?

My code:

```
request5 = requests.get('https://apieds.betfair.com.au/api/eds/meeting-races/v4?_ak=nzIFcwyWhrlwYMrh&countriesGroup=%5B%5B%22GB%22,%22IE%22%5D%5D&eventTypeId=4339&marketStartingAfter=2020-07-25T16:00:00.000Z&marketStartingBefore=2020-07-26T15:59:59.999Z')
json5 = request5.json()
for m in json5[0]['meetings']:
    for r in m['races']:
        bhevents.append((m['venue'],r['marketName']))
```

Output of code:

```
 ('Sale', 'R10 440m Gr5'), ('Sale', 'R11 440m Gr5'), ('Sale', 'R12 440m Vets')
```

Desired output of code:

```
('Sale', 'R10'), ('Sale', 'R11'), ('Sale', 'R12')
```

Comment: Seems like `bhevents.append((m['venue'],r['marketName'].split()[0]))` would do.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove all the char after any `" "` in `r['marketName']`. You can do easily by using **split()** (see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)).
By default any whitespace is a separator and it return an array with every part of the string between spaces.

So `'R10 440m Gr5'` became `['R10,'440m','Gr5']`. You have to choose the first element.

Your code will be:

```
for m in json5[0]['meetings']:
    for r in m['races']:
        bhevents.append((m['venue'],r['marketName'].split()[0]))
```